# What is the problem with this code?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, newline, constants

The compile error I'm getting is "newline in constant"
The error occurs where the four asterisks are (`****`).
I can't debug, because the solution won't build successfully.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TNClicked(fullImgURL, TNID) {
    document.getElementById("<%= this.imgFull.ClientID %>").src = fullImgURL;

    var pnlFullImage = document.getElementById("<%= this.pnlFullImage.ClientID %>");
    if (pnlFullImage.style.visibility != "visible")
        pnlFullImage.style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("<%= this.tcImage.ClientID %>").innerHTML = TNID;
    //document.forms[0].ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cntBody$hfImage.value = TNID;
    //****document.getElementById("<%= this.hfImage").setAttribute("value", TNID);
    //document.getElementById("<%= this.hfImage.ClientID %>").value = TNID;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing a %> on the **** line

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing %> in that string?

Comment: Yes I am missing that. I feel like a dunce. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try commenting out your comments using

```
<%--


--%>
```

and close this

```
("<%= this.hfImage%>")
```